# Check LINQ return is null for observable collection List

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm, observablecollection

```
Data1 = new ObservableCollection<dsData1>(from itmGetAllData2 in GetAllData2
                                          where itmGetAllData2.Name == strName
                                          select itmGetAllData2)[0];
```

Above LINQ is working fine if there is a match between `itmGetAllData2.Name == strName` but if there is no record matching `strName` it is throwing an error.

Can anyone suggest how to handle this? I tried doing

```
.DefaultIfEmpty().Max(itmGetAllData2 => itmGetAllData2 == null ? "" : itmGetAllData2);
```

but it's giving casting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could be simplified to:

```
Data1 = GetAllData2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == strName);
```

If no matches are found, `Data1` will be `null`. (that's what the `OrDefault` part adds) If you want to substitute a different value for null, you can do, e.g.

```
Data1 = GetAllData2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == strName) ?? new dsData1();
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are trying to access the first element of an empty query.

Use `FirstOrDefault`

```
var result = GetAllData2.FirstOrDefault(ad => ad.Name = strName);

if (result != null)
{
   // Initalize your ObservableCollection here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get this error when there is no match because [0] is trying to access the first object of a list that doesn't have any objects. Do this instead:

```
Data1 = GetAllData2.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == strName);
```

This will be the first item like you want, or null if none were found.